# Not able Scan using redis template

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to use SCAN http://redis.io/commands/scan to iterate over all the keys present in redis. But the Redis template provided by spring do not have any scan() method. Is there any trick to use the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `RedisCallback` on `RedisOperations` to do so.

```java
redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Iterable<byte[]>>() {

  @Override
  public Iterable<byte[]> doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {

    List<byte[]> binaryKeys = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    Cursor<byte[]> cursor = connection.scan(ScanOptions.NONE);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
      binaryKeys.add(cursor.next());
    }

    try {
      cursor.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // do something meaningful
    }

    return binaryKeys;
  }
});
```

Comment: Available from version 1.4.0 (of spring-data-redis).

Comment: I am getting java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: @coolscitist there's an issue where redis returns an empty result for a scan interation that got interpreted wrong (see [DATAREDIS-417](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-417)). Will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not return the resource to the pool. This exception always happens since the cursor is explicitly closed?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> keys = (Set<String>) redisTemplate.execute((RedisCallback<Set<String>>) connection -> {
            Cursor<byte[]> cursor = null;
            Set<String> keysTmp = new HashSet<>();
            try {
                cursor = connection.scan(new ScanOptions.ScanOptionsBuilder().match(keyPrefix + "*").count(10000).build());
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    keysTmp.add(new String(cursor.next()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (Objects.nonNull(cursor) && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        cursor.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return keysTmp;
        });
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your code, so my novice eyes can understand why this solves the issue?