# Is it safe to use Spring Redis keys?

Tags: spring, redis, key

I want to search keys with the string pattern. I don't see SCAN is straight forward as Keys do.

redistemplate.opsForSet().getOperations().keys(pattern);

This is so straight forward, so if I have my value as my key, I can do search and also sorting to an extent. But my only problem is that there is a warning stating not to use KEYS command. Not sure if Spring has handled it, please provide your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `KEYS` (http://redis.io/commands/keys) a debug command. Running it in redis-cli on your development instance is perfectly fine, but don't use it in code that will eventually end up on your production instance.

Depending on the size of your redis database and the pattern used with `KEYS`, the command can potentially take a long time to execute. During that time the redis server will not be able to service any other commands.

`SCAN` may not be as straight-forward, but it is the right way to enumerate keys without slowing the server down. And you'll find plenty of samples for Spring, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30260108/3677188

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but scenario is little tricky. I deal with billion of records, working with billion of records in DB is easy but i do want to have it in inline memory apart from DB. So, I choose redis, I tried some options like dividing the records into multiple lists and store in redis. But then, I can't do sort or search on the values. So the next step is storing the key as value, I can do the search on the pattern matching only KEYS.

Comment: I just don't understand how to use SCAN. I need to match pattern. I have the below keys,

>Keys *
>Key0-Test+XXXXX
>Key0-Production+XXXXX
>Key0-EVAL+XXXXX
>Key0-Test-PreProduction+XXXXX
>Key0-Test-EVAL+XXXXX
 and so on,
Now, I want to find all the keys matching *Test*. Please let me know how it is possible in SCAN.